# EC2 Ubuntu NGINX config HTTPS Redirect giving me error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

## Background

I've got an Ubuntu machine running on an AWS EC2 instance (Node/Express app), with its SSL certs setup using Certificate Manager and a Load Balancer. This worked fine for going to my site directly using https, e.g, `https://example.com`. However, using `http`, resulted in an insecure connection.

Checking on whynopadlock.com, I'm told my web server is not forcing HTTPS. My web server is setup using NGINX as a reverse proxy to my private IP of my EC2 instance. I've hunted around and can't quite seem to find a proper example like mine, although I've tried to piece together what I was able to find.

When I attempt to setup a force HTTPS redirect, I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

## Before: Original Nginx Config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{MASKED_EC2_INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP_FOR_POST}}:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

> Notes: This config allowed https://example.com to load fine, however there was no redirect if navigating to the site using http://example.com and resulted an insecure connection.

## After: NGINX Config after adding HTTPS Redirect

```
# HTTP
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 301   https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS
server {
    listen       443 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://{{MASKED_EC2_INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP_FOR_POST}}:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

## Issue

I see now that when I load the domain with http, I am redirected successfully to **https**, however I am receiving the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing or may be doing wrong in my config?

Comment: If you have ALB, why do you use nginx for https?

Comment: @Marcin What is ALB? I was trying to setup a redirect in nginx since I’m using the reverse proxy as a layer between my EC2 node app. I thought maybe it would make more sense to do a redirect in nginx than in the express side of things? Would love to know a simpler or better way if you have suggestions! Thank your taking time to respond to my question! 

Comment: You wrote "Certificate Manager and a Load Balancer." thus I assumed you are using AWS load balancer?

Comment: @Marcin — sorry, I understand now! Yes I’m using an ALB. Is there a way to force https / https redirect via ALB? You are correct right now I used Certificate Manager to create an SSL cert, then setup an ALB using it. I also then used Route 53 to point my domain over to AWS DNS, and created an A record to point to my load balancer. The cert is working, but root of my question is wondering how to force any http domain requests to use https. Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ALB, you can **redirect http to https on the ALB** itself. AWS provides a guide how to set it up:

> [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

The process involves creating http listener and adding **redirection action**  to it instead of regular forward rule. This way you don't have to perform any changes to your instances, as all is taken care of by the ALB.

Also since you are using AWS Certificate Manager you have to use ALB as ACM SSL cert can't be used on instance. The ACM can only be used on a load balancer (ALB, CLB or NLB), CloudFront distro or API Gateway.